# get only sub category ID

Tags: categories

i need to get only sub category ID. i already get sub category id but it coming with main category id too

bellow is code

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<option value=".<?php
     foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
     echo $category->cat_ID . ' '. $category->cat_name ;
     }
     ?>">
              <?php
     foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
     echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
     }
     ?>

</option>
<?php endwhile; 
?>
```

after code my rendered code is like bellow

```
<select id="filter-select">
          <option value="*" selected="selected">all</option>
                    <option value=".15 8 ">Magdalena Venta </option>
                    <option value=".15 8 ">Bo. de la Magdalena</option>
                    <option value=".16 8 ">Juan Venta</option>
                    <option value=".17 8 ">Club de G</option>
                    <option value=".21 8 ">Fraccionamiento Viñedos Venta</option>
</select>
```

after value all is sub category id like 15, 16, 17,21 but **8** is is main category ID. i don't want this **8** coming.

so mainly i want to get like this  `<option value="child category ID ">Child Category Name </option>`

i am trying still. if i get can get any solution it will post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only want a `select` form field that has a categories children, then simply go with [`wp_list_categories()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_list_categories/)

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'child_of' => 'your parent cat ID',
) );
```

Depending on your use case, you could as well use

- [`get_the_category()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_category/) and its `get_the_categories` filter

  ```
  apply_filters( 'get_the_categories', $categories );
  ```
- [`get_the_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_terms/) and its filter (the function is called internally by `get_the_category()`:

  ```
  apply_filters( 'get_the_terms', $terms, $post->ID, $taxonomy );
  ```
- [`get_categories()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_categories/), pass a special key to the arguments input array (e.g. `my-special-list`) that you then check in a callback on the filter inside the function and alter the output there. The function calls `get_terms()` *after* the filters callbacks get called.

  ```
  apply_filters( 'get_categories_taxonomy', $taxonomy, $args );
  ```
- [`get_term_children( $term_ID, 'category' )`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_term_children/)

**Edit** The main queried object can always be retrieved using `get_queried_object()`. And there's a function to extract its ID: [`get_queried_object_id()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object_id/).

Comment: thanks for reply.actually i am apply that on category.php so category id is not fix... i am still trying many way. let see if i can. mainly i want to show all of child category name and id show like  <option value="ID">NAME</option>

Comment: @AccoreLTD See update. Also: `wp_list_categories()` will build you what you need.

Comment: thanks once again for quick response.. actually i can not figure out how to apply this :( i am no so expert for coding yet

Comment: Use `get_queried_object_id()` when a function asks for the ID of the currently displayed category archive page: `wp_list_pages( array( 'child_of' => get_queried_object_id(), ) );` for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap it in an additional `if` statement to weed out categories that don't have parents (IE, top-level categories), like so:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
     foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
       if($category->parent) { // check if this category has a parent
          echo '<option value="' . $category->cat_ID . ' '. $category->cat_name . '">' . $category->cat_name . '</option>'; 
       }
     } 
    endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. actually you way just coming main category name and id. not child/sub category

Comment: I think you want the opposite in your `if` test, if it has a parent it's not a top-level category.

Comment: You're right @milo, it was backward. I've updated the code to look for categories with parents. thanks! Hope it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [wp_dropdown_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) and use *child_of* parameter to current page's category.

```
<?php $obj_id = get_queried_object_id(); // category ID ?>
<?php wp_dropdown_categories(array(
    'child_of' => $obj_id,
    'hide_empty' => false // use this to show ALL sub-categories, even empty ones; otherwise omit this
)); ?>
```